# In Darktable, is there a way to bind a keyboard shortcut to 'History Stack - Discard'?

Tags: darktable

Sometimes I like to see how various Darktable styles look on a particular image. As far as I've been able to discover, the only way to "undo" a style after it's been applied - apart from manually resetting all the modules used in style - is to pop back out to the lighttable and discard the history stack.

Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut to quickly accomplish 'History Stack - Discard' within the darkroom?

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the bottom entry ("0 - original") in the history module on the left panel in darkroom mode, or any other point above that in history, to reset the image to that point. Any image operation you then perform will replace (as in completely discard) the history above this point. It's not as convenient as a keyboard shortcut, but it does allow you to try different styles, etc, on an image that you've already made changes to that you wish to keep (one that's already cropped, for instance).

One thing that you *could* bind a keyboard shortcut to would be a style that applied all modules likely to be used in the other styles in question, but in an "off" state... you could even bind the same key to compress the history to keep things uncluttered. You know, if you like hacky workarounds. :P

Comment: Cool, good to know. Thanks. BTW, that does still work in v2.

Comment: Also, if you still have your skin retouching style/preset, I'd be interested in checking it out. I've been using Linux Mint as my primary OS for a few years, but I've hung onto a Windows box primarily for Lightroom and a few plugins. The 'Portraiture' plugin is one of them. I'm still new to Darktable, but after gaining some understanding of the UI and playing around with it a bit, I think I'm pretty close to making the switch, especially if I can find usable alternatives to the plugins I use most frequently.

Comment: (I just created some presets and styles to mimic most of the toning options from the 'BWStyler' plugin I've used for years).

Comment: `0 - original` is not the same as what you see when opening a file the first time in darktable. base curve and sharpening are automatically applied.